# User Access Rights getting cleared in Odoo 8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I'm trying to learn Odoo and developing a module. For the same, I just created 2 new user groups. ie. `Parent` and `Faculty`. I used the following code,

```
<record id="group_parent" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Parent</field>
</record>
<record id="group_faculty" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Faculty</field>
</record>
```

It worked fine and I can see these groups under the `Access Rights` tab in user's form view.

[image]

Then I was able to assign `Faculty` option for a user. But when I upgrade my module, it's getting reset the user's access rights.

[image]

After upgrading my module, how it looks like is:

[image]

In the `data` block, I used to try with `noupdate="1"` and `noupdate="0"`, but no use. I'm still getting the same issue. Is there any other places which should be taken into account to fix this issue?

It will be appreciable, if anyone can tell me the reason for this issue.

Comment: Try adding in the "data" tag noupdate="1"

Comment: Thanks! I tried it by adding `noupdate="1"` in the `data` tag, but no use. Still getting the same issue.

Comment: try too with noupdate="0", anyway edit your question with this too please!

Answer (score 0):

In your data block set the option noupdate to 1:

```
<data noupdate="1">
...
</data>
```

Take into account that this only works if you are updating your module. If you are doing a reinstallation, this flag will be bypassed and your changes will still be overwritten.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to update the module but getting the issue. I tried `noupdate="1"` and `noupdate="0"`, but no use.